# Java - Appending a tree to a branch of another tree by given UNIQUE index number

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a java class like this,

```
    class Block{
        private int index;
        private Block left;
        private Block right;

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public Block setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
            return this;
        }

        public Block getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public Block setLeft(Block left) {
            this.left = left;
            return this;
        }

        public Block getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public Block setRight(Block right) {
            this.right = right;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Then, I've created two trees like this using setter methods.

```
    Block tree1 = new Block()
        .setLeft(new Block()
                        .setLeft(new Block())
                        .setRight(new Block())
        )
        .setRight(new Block()
                        .setLeft(new Block())
                        .setRight(new Block())
        );
```

and,

```
    Block tree2 = new Block()
        .setRight(new Block()
                .setRight(new Block()
                        .setRight(new Block()
                                .setLeft(new Block())
                                .setLeft(new Block())
                        )
                )
        );
```

So, I would like to have a method like,

```
int blockIndex = 3;
boolean replace = false;//add if new, else do nothing
tree1.appendBlock(blockIndex,tree2,replace);
```

Trees should be able to create directly (like tree1 and tree2) and also within loops. 
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is kinda lack of logic: to which side we should add, if requested index not found?

Comment: All the indexes should be unique. If the given index is not found, it should be able to throw an exception. Like java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception in ArrayList.

Comment: So, if `tree1.appendBlock(blockIndex,tree2,replace);` can't find node with index `blockIndex`, it should throw an error?

Comment: Eh, but at which point? For example, we have root tree node. It's left leaf is a mere blind leaf with index of, like, `2`. And right leaf is itself a tree, with node with index `20` somewhere down the tree. So, we're running `root.appendBlock(20,tree2,whatever);`, its goes inside left leaf of root node and finds nothing with index `20`... And what, throw exception?

Comment: That's the thing. You need to search the entire tree to find the leaf by given index. If the given index cannot be found in the tree, there comes the exception.

Comment: But thats not something `appendBlock` should do. Because `appendBlock` doesn't knows by itself, if index doesn't found in entire tree. My poin was, where exception should be thrown? definitely not in `appendBlock` method...

Comment: I get it. Do you have a better way to do this? I'm planing to create a separate class for root node like `RootBlock` inherited by `Block` class and including `appendBlock` method only in `RootBlock` as it can access all the sub trees/leafs and parent-less, and find the Block by given index. What do you think of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here possible solution:

```
class Block {

    ...

    boolean appendBlock(int atIndex, Block tree, boolean replace) {
        if (left == right == null)
            return false;

        if ((left != null) && (left.index == atIndex) {
            if (replace) 
                setLeft(tree);
        } else
            if ((right != null) && (right.index == atIndex)) {
                if (replace) 
                    setRight(tree);
            } else
                if ((left == null) || !left.appendBlock(atIndex, tree, replace))
                    if ((right == null) || !right.appendBlock(atIndex, tree, replace))
                        return false;

        return true;
    }

    ...

}
```

Usage:

```
...

replace = false;
if (!tree1.appendBlock(index, tree2, replace))
    throw Exception(String.format("Child node with index %d not found", index));
```

When `replace = false` - method searches for child node with specified index and returns `false` if not found.

If `replace = true`, then if child node with specified index was found - it will be replaced with specified `Block` node.

**Upd.**

To make it always throw an exception if node was not found, following trick could be used:

```
// define actual searcher function as private util
// it's safe to call it as it's only indicates success with boolean
// result, so no exceptions would be thrown
protected boolean appendBlockIfFound(int atIndex, Block tree, boolean replace) {
    if (left == right == null)
        return false;

    // same code as above in appendBlock() method
    ...

    return true;
}

// ... and the real worker, exposed to the class user (developer)
// will throw exception on error
public void appendBlock(int atIndex, Block tree, boolean replace) {
    if (!appendBlockIfFound(atIndex, tree, replace))
        throw Exception(String.format("Child node with index %d not found", atIndex));
}
```

**Upd. 2**

Searcher function for non-fixed amount of childnodes:

```
class Block extends ArrayList<Block> {

    ...

    public Block(int childs) {
        super(childs);
        while (childs > 0)
            add(null);
    }

    private boolean appendBlockIfFound(int atIndex, Block tree, boolean replace) {
        if (size() <= 0)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            Block child = get(i);
            if (child == null)
                continue;
            if (child.index == atIndex) {
                if (replace)
                  set(i, tree);
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (Block child: this)
          if ((child != null) && child.appendBlockIfFound(atIndex, tree, replace))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Block set(int index, Block child) {
      super.set(index, child);
      return this;
    }

    ...

}
```

Usage:

```
class TenBlock extends Block {

    public TenBlock() {
        super(10);
    }

}
```

... and then:

```
Block root = new TenBlock();

Block child10 = root.get(9);

root.set(5, (new TenBlock()).set(2, new TenBlock()))
    .set(6, new TenBlock())
```

Comment: I agree that using the boolean return value seems preferable when calling `appendBlock()` recursively. But in the outermost invocation, an exception would probably be better because it cannot be ignored.

Comment: this will requre addition of some dummy parameter to find out, if current called `append...` is that `outermost` invocation. But that's an overhead, which with recursion will only grow bigger...

Comment: I agree, finding out if the invocation is the outermost sounds cumbersome. But you could catch and re-throw exceptions instead of using the return value in the first place. You would just have to catch for left and right invocation separately, i.e. only if two exceptions are caught, re-throw the exception. But I'm not really sure if that wouldn't be abusing the exception concept a little bit.

Comment: This is it! This can't do without returning a boolean. How this should be implemented if a parent block has a list of child Blocks with size `n`?

Comment: @MichaelJaros, you're definitely right with `abusing the exception concept`. Exceptions are designed for identifying `flaws` in program's lifecycle. But not just that, the instantiation of `Exception` is _really_ a time/memory heavy operation. So, if you going to use try/catch mechanism for such a minor usecase, and additionally in recursion... Just prepare for _PAIN_... It would definitely ache after some time of program product development cycle xD